# Python-join two dataframes to find same row values having different values in corresponding rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, group-by

I have a dataframe of the following format:

```
#join two dataframes to find same row values having different values in corresponding rows
f = pd.DataFrame({'TS': [101, 102,103], 'date': ['2012-01-18','2014-11-16','2016-08-20'] , 'lbl': ['f', 'f', 'f']})
m = pd.DataFrame({'TS': [101, 101,104], 'date': ['2012-05-08','2013-01-26','2016-04-30'] , 'lbl': ['m', 'm', 'm']})
```

I want to join them and order them by their TS and dates 
ie I need to know which occurrence of TS comes after the other:

the final df after operation will look like:

```
TS      date     lbl
101   2012-01-08  f
101   2013-05-08  m
101   2013-01-26  m
102   2014-11-16  f
103   2016-08-20  f
104   2016-04-30  m
```

i tried

```
result2=result.sort_values(['TS','date'],ascending=[True,True])
```

but that dosent give me appropriate results, I want same TS values with different date values together.do i use `groupby`?

Comment: concat then sort values: `pd.concat((m,f)).sort_values(['TS','date'])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
result = pd.concat([f,m], ignore_index=True).sort_values(['TS','date'])
print (result)
    TS        date lbl
0  101  2012-01-18   f
3  101  2012-05-08   m
4  101  2013-01-26   m
1  102  2014-11-16   f
2  103  2016-08-20   f
5  104  2016-04-30   m
```

Comment: @jezerael Did what you asked , but what i want is this https://imgur.com/a/9L0kDbi  
ie, values with same TS number and sequential date values need to come one after the other.
i also tried result.groupby('TRAINSET').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['date'])) but that dosent give me appropriate results as well

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - hmmm, in real data not working, because sometimes space and sometimes no space between 203 and TC